# How to create a file and save scraped data in it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've made this script but I tried few options to save data, but I keep messing up the code. How to save extracted data into and csv, or into an excel file?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.privredni-imenik.com/pretraga?abcd=&keyword=&cities_id=0&category_id=0&sub_category_id=0&page=1"
current_page = 1

while current_page < 200:
    print(current_page)
    url = base_url + str(current_page)
    #current_page += 1
    r = requests.get(url)
    zute_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    firme = zute_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'jobs-item'})

    for title in firme:
        title1 = title.findAll('h6')[0].text
        print(title1)
        adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[0].text
        print(adresa)
        kontakt = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[1].text
        print(kontakt)
        print('\n')
        page_line = "{title1}\n{adresa}\n{kontakt}".format(
            title1=title1,
            adresa=adresa,
            kontakt=kontakt
        )
    current_page += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get a CSV would be to print each line separated by commas, and then use the operating system's ">" to write to a file.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.privredni-imenik.com/pretraga?abcd=&keyword=&cities_id=0&category_id=0&sub_category_id=0&page=1"
current_page = 1


with open('scrape_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as scrape_results:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(scrape_results)

    while current_page < 200:
        url = base_url + str(current_page)
        r = requests.get(url)
        zute_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        firme = zute_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'jobs-item'})

        for title in firme:
            title1 = title.findAll('h6')[0].text
            adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[0].text
            kontakt = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[1].text
            csvwriter.writerow([current_page, title1, adresa, kontakt])

        current_page += 1
```

Comment: Strange now it does'nt scrape ,,kontakt`` at all . I just get title and adresa. But it saves into an csv as excpected

Comment: OOps. My mistake i found that it scraped all as excepted! Thank You!